# Split the string one variable having multiple space

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string contain data = `partname partno modelname qty binqty`,
i need to split this string but problem is `partname` contain colur code data and multiple space in this variable e.g `chrome,assy black, typhon n silver mettalic`

```cs
string PartName ,PartName ,Qty 
string[] ScanData = TxtScanData.Text.Split(' ');

if(ScanData.Length >= 3)
{
    PartName = ScanData[0];
    PartNo = ScanData[1];
    Qty = ScanData[3];
}
else
{
    PartName = "";
    PartNo = "";
    Qty = "";
}
```

i am expecting get the partname data in multiple space

Comment: This sounds like a problem in your data format as much as anything else. If you have "a b c d e" then how do you *expect* to know whether that's ("a b", "c", "d e"); ("a b c", "d", e") or any of the other possibilities? If it's actually only *one* part of the data that could contain spaces, it should be feasible - but we could really do with significantly more examples in order to help you.

Comment: Yes one part of the data contain more space, how can i handle this part

Comment: As I said before, we could really do with significantly more examples in order to help you. (I suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and really take some time to think how you could make your question as clear as possible. Multiple sample inputs with the desired outputs would be a good start.

Comment: blog literally helpful

Comment: Parse off the last 4 fields one at a time looking for the last space in the remaining line. What's left remaining is just your partname.